# "Launch screens may not set custom class names"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm trying to set the initial view controller to a custom class. In previous versions this worked but for some reason I cannot do it now.

I have a `UIViewController` class (`IntroVC`). In the storyboard I created a new `View Controller` object and set it's class (`Identity Inspector` -> `Custom Class` -> `Class`) to `IntroVC`. `IntroVC` is a `.swift` file with functions `viewDidLoad()` and `didReceiveMemoryWarning()` of `class IntroVC: UIViewController`.

Here are screenshots of XCode

#### Error

[image: Error]

#### IntroVC

[image: IntroVC]

#### Storyboard

[image: Storyboard]

Anyone know how to solve this? What's up with this version of XCode?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I made a really simple mistake.

This error occurred when a custom class was set in `LaunchScreen.storyboard`. I should have set my custom `IntroVC` class in `Main.storyboard`.

Setting the initial VC class in `LaunchScreen.storyboard` to `UIViewController` and the initial VC class in `Main.storyboard` to `IntroVC` fixed the problem.

XCode 7.0.1 is fine. The mistake is my own.

Comment: And you can see why this would be. In the launch screen storyboard, we are launching; your code has not run yet. So none of your custom classes exist. The only view controller class you can use is a plain vanilla UIViewController.

Comment: I meet the same error when set launchScreen's ViewController to a customized ViewController. So the thing is launchScreen doesn't allow any code, since your app is not launched in that phase, then your code would never be ran.

Answer (score 3):

Go through your View Controllers in Main.storyboard and make sure you don't have one that is **both** set to a custom class:

[image]

**and** has "Is Initial View Controller" checked:

[image]

You can only do one or the other.  Somehow I had "Is Initial View Controller" still checked by mistake, and it took me a while to hunt that down!

Answer (score 1):

Check if you're changing the "LaunchScreen.xib" file view class in the identity inspector. It should be a standard UIView, maybe you set it to a view controller class by accident.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs due to if you are set the class name for the `LaunchScreen.Storyboard` file in the `Identity Inspector`. Just remove the class name and it will work fine.